# Redux Material UI RadioButtonGroup - Selected input keeps resetting due to weird redux state issue

Tags: redux, material-ui, redux-form

I've got a form with multiple different types of inputs, including text inputs, checkboxes, and radio buttons. Due to the nature of data surrounding a particular radio button set, I've had to extract it into its own component. What's weird is that any time any of the other radio buttons are selected, it causes the radio button group to become unselected.

I have a "Yes" and "No" option that map to true/false. When it's true, an element appears on the screen with checkboxes. When false, nothing special happens. When it's true and I select another radio button from another radio button group, it works fine, however when I select "No"/false, and then select a radio button, it resets. I've been completely confused at this problem for days and since I inherited this project, I'm not exactly sure what is wrong or what I need to do.

Here is my code, if anyone could provide some insight

Here is the code relevant to the radio button group from within the redux form:

```
<div className="page-form__block">
    <p> Is there any PPE associated with this work? </p>
    <Field
        name="ppe"
        component={props =>
          <PPE
            {...props}
          />
        }
    />
</div>
```

And here is the actual component for the RadioButtonGroup:

```
import React from 'react';
import { RadioButton, RadioButtonGroup } from 'material-ui/RadioButton';
// import CheckboxList from '../../components/CheckboxList';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import { find, findIndex } from 'lodash';

const safetyList = [
  { _id: '1',
    details: 'Hard Hats' },
  { _id: '2',
    details: 'Boots' },
  { _id: '3',
    details: 'Long Sleeves' },
  { _id: '4',
    details: 'Safety Googles' },
  { _id: '5',
    details: 'Steel Toe Shoes' },
  { _id: '6',
    details: 'Gloves' },
  { _id: '7',
    details: 'Dust Masks' },
  { _id: '8',
    details: 'High Vis Reflective Vests' },
  { _id: '9',
    details: 'Harness' },
  { _id: '10',
    details: 'Face Shield' },
  { _id: '11',
    details: 'Hearing Protection' },
  { _id: '12',
    details: 'Jeans/Long Pants' },
];

class Ppeinput extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      list: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.input.value.list) {
      this.setState({ list: this.props.input.value.list });
    }
  }

  toggle(event) {

    let open = event.target.value;
    if (open === 'true') {
      this.props.input.onChange({
        open: true,
        list: this.state.list,
      });
    } else {
      this.props.input.onChange({
        open: false,
        list: [],
      });
    }
  }

  onCheck(event, isInputChecked) {
    let initialArray = this.state.list;
    if (isInputChecked) {
      initialArray = [...initialArray, find(safetyList, { _id: event.target.value })];
    } else {
      initialArray.splice(findIndex(initialArray, { _id: event.target.value }), 1);
    }
    this.setState({ list: initialArray });
    // console.log(initialArray);
    this.props.input.onChange({
      open: true,
      list: initialArray,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isOpen = this.props.input.value.open; // Get state of selected input
    const { meta } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="page-form__block">
        <RadioButtonGroup name="ppe_input" defaultSelected={isOpen} onChange={::this.toggle}>
          <RadioButton value={true} label="Yes" />
          <RadioButton value={false} label="No" />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
        {meta.touched && meta.error && <div className="form-error">{meta.error}</div>}

        { isOpen ? (<div className="ppe_field">
          <u> Select the PPE </u>
          <ul>
          {safetyList.map((item) => {
            return find(this.props.input.value.list, { _id: item._id}) ? (
              <li key={item._id}>
                <Checkbox
                  label={item.details}
                  value={item._id}
                  onCheck={this.onCheck.bind(this)}
                  defaultChecked={true}
                />
              </li>
            ) : (
              <li key={item._id}>
                <Checkbox
                  label={item.details}
                  value={item._id}
                  onCheck={this.onCheck.bind(this)}
                />
              </li>
            )
          })}
          </ul>
        </div>) : (<div></div>) }

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Ppeinput;
```

Redux is still a weird concept to grasp for me, so if anyone could provide insight, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So for whatever reason, my version of React/Redux in this particular instance does not like the raw `false` value. It likes `"false"`. So basically, for my component, I changed out any instance of `true/false` with `"true"/"false"` and now everything works fine. I've actually run into this issue before inside of React, and I still have no idea why this happens. But either way, this is the solution I've found. Cheers!